# What does 1:4 t-BuOH/H2O mean?

Tags: applied-chemistry

I've got a - probably rather not-so-smart question regarding chemical reactions. In many publications, the authors say that they used *e.g.* ***t*-BuOH/H<sub>2</sub>O (1:4)** as solvent. What exactly does 1:4 mean? Is it one part of *t*-BuOH of 4 parts of solvent in total, *i.e.* $\pu{50 mL}$ *t*-BuOH and $\pu{150 mL}$ of H<sub>2</sub>O to give a total volume of $\pu{200 mL}$  (4*50), or is it one part of *t*-BuOH and four times as much water, *i.e.* $\pu{50 mL}$  *t*-BuOH and $\pu{200 mL}$ H<sub>2</sub>O to give a total volume of $\pu{250 mL}$?

Or otherwise said, do I add both numbers to get the total amount of parts, or is the higher number already the total number of parts? In my first example, we could say, that **4** is the total number of parts. In my second example, you'd have to add both numbers to get the total number of parts, *i.e.* 1 + 4 = 5 parts in total, one of which is *t*-BuOH and four of which are H<sub>2</sub>O.

Comment: one part of t-BuOH and four times as much water

Comment: In literature, when in experimental section, if it says 1:4 of solvent system but didn't verify, most of the time it means 1 part of one solvent and 4 part of the other solvent in volume units (total: 1+ 4, regardless they are additive or not). This is through specifically in chromatography. If it's not in volume, the authors would definitely verify whether it is $w/v$ or $v/w$ or $w/w$.

Answer (score 5):

As @MaxW already pointed out, 1:4 means that you have to use four times as much water as *t*-BuOH. But I also want to explain why this is, because you'll probably see this more often.

In fact, 1:4 is a ratio, so what it represents is the ratio between *t*-BuOH and H<sub>2</sub>O:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{ratio} &= \frac{V(\ce{t-BuOH})}{V(\ce{H2O})}\\
&= \frac{50\text{ mL}}{200\text{ mL}}\\
&= \frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
$$

And that's why your ratio says 1:4. You could have just rearranged the equation:

$$
\begin{align}
1:4 = \frac{1}{4} = \frac{V(\ce{t-BuOH})}{V(\ce{H2O})}\\
\implies V(\ce{H2O}) = 4 \cdot V(\ce{t-BuOH})
\end{align}
$$

Here, both components, water and *tert*-butanol, are liquids.  Sometimes the implicit assumption the ratio refering to the ratio of volumes is expressed explicitly by an indication like (tBuOH-water, 1:4, v/v).  Conversely, a mass ratio sometimes may be expressed by m/m.

Side note: As discussed on [ChemSE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58286/explain-volume-contraction-in-mixtures-of-alcohol-and-water) and [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23534/how-does-volume-contraction-in-solvent-mixing-work), or in the literature ([example](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.8b00850)), be aware of the possibility of a volume contraction.  Thus, measure the volumes of the components independently from each other before pouring them into one container in common (e.g., for chromatography).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that exactly 50 ml of t-BuOH and 200 ml water will not yield exactly 250 ml of solution.