# Is the density of a two-component mixture always between the densities of its individual components?

Tags: mixtures, density

There exist eutectic mixtures, in which the freezing point of the mixture is below those of either component of the mixture, i.e., the freezing point of the mixture is not intermediate between that of each component, but is instead lower than both.

Can the same occur for density? Are there mixtures of substances $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ such that either $\rho_\mathrm{mix}$ is greater than both $\rho_\ce{A}$ and $\rho_\ce{B},$ or $\rho_\mathrm{mix}$ is less than than both $\rho_\ce{A}$ and $\rho_\ce{B}?$

Or is the density of a two-component mixture always bracketed by (i.e., some intermediate value between) the densities of its individual components?

Comment: May I ask why this question is being downvoted? It seems a relevant question to those exploring chemistry, though perhaps technically more in the realm of physics?

Comment: No, the density of a mixture of A and B is not necessarily the weighted average of the densities of A and B. This is equivalent to saying that, when mixing two liquids, the total volume is not necessarily the sum of the two starting volumes; look [Partial molar volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_molar_property) up. A common example is water-ethanol mixtures.

Comment: The problem is how it's written.  It wasn't sufficiently precise, plus you're not actually asking if density is additive. Densities are never simply additive, since density is an intensive property (like temperature -- you can see that temperature is not additive). You're asking whether the density of a 2-component mixture is always bracketed by (i.e., some intermediate value between) the densities of its individual components.  I've edited your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Well, *optical density* can often be treated as additive for the non-reacting mix, but I see no reason why mass density must ever be additive. Maybe have a look at the [Wikipedia page on intensive and extensive properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties)

Comment: Even using the logic of density compared to the nature of compounds tells you that variations will occur. Mass will obviously stay the same but volume can be drastically different compared to the pure elements.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23534/how-does-volume-contraction-in-solvent-mixing-work https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23534/is-it-possible-to-have-volumesolution-volumesolvent-volumesolute https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83765/is-it-possible-to-have-volumesolution-volumesolvent-before-adding-solute

Comment: @Mithoron  Those answers all give examples of volume contraction, which is different from what's being asked. Volume contraction is a necessary *but not sufficient* criterion for the mixture to have a density that exceeds that of its individual components. Correspondingly, none of the volume contraction examples in those answers meet the OP's criterion:  Ethanol-water solutions never have a density greater than that of pure water (https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ethanol-water-mixture-density-d_2162.html) and NaCl(aq) solutions never have a density greater than that of NaCl(s) (2.16 g/cm^3).

Comment: ....continued:  http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/pshapley/genchem1/l21/1.html  [Assuming, of course, the pure components and the mixture are measured under the same conditions, particularly T and p.]

Answer (score 11):

**No**, there is no law that requires the density of a mixture to fall between the densities of pure components. It does so most of the time, but the exceptions are not unheard of. Here's one.

Water: density $1.00\ \rm{g/cm^3}$
Hydrazine: $1.02\ \rm{g/cm^3}$
Hydrazine hydrate: $1.03\ \rm{g/cm^3}$

So it goes.

Comment: Any examples of the opposite, where the density of the mixture is lower than that of both the pure components?

Comment: Can't think of any, but there is no fundamental law forbidding that, either.

Comment: Ethanol/benzene and ethanol/toluene: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Excess-volume-of-ethanol-benzene-top-and-ethanol-toluene-bottom-present_fig2_282982793. Benzene/m-xylene: http://www.ddbst.com/en/EED/VE/VE0%20Benzene%3Bm-Xylene.php.

Comment: Positive excess volume _per se_ is **not** enough to ensure the condition in question.